# Passing a method call to a constructor,java

Tags: java

Assignment:
Time class:

give it 3 private data members for hour, minute, and second. Use type long or int.

If you use int you must cast inside the ctors.

add a no-arg ctor that uses code like that in Listing 2.6 on p38 to assign values
to hour, minute, and second from the current time.

add another ctor that will take a single long parameter named elapseTime (better
would be elapsedTime), a number for milliseconds since the Unix epoch date.
this second ctor will also use code as per Listing 2.6 to set the data members
for that elapsed time since the epoch.

add a getter for each data member. Each getter will require only a single statement.

Getters are needed because the data members are private.

add a toString method that returns the hours, minutes, and seconds for a Time object.

here is my class Time() code, my setTime() code represents the book reference mentioned above.

package chapter_10;

```
public class Time {
    private long hour;
    private long minute;
    private long second;

    public Time() {

    }
    public void setTime(long elapsedTime){
       long millisecond = System.currentTimeMillis();
       second = millisecond / 1000;
       minute = second / 60;
       hour = minute /60;
       //equate for current time.
       second = second %60;
       minute = minute %60;
       hour = hour %24;
    }

    public long getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public long getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public long getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public  String toString(){
       return getHour() + ":" + getMinute() + ":" + getSecond();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense at the moment. What do you mean by "call a method into another constructor"? Please explain what you're trying to *achieve*, not the means you think are appropriate to achieve it...

Comment: Ok well i thought i was asking what i was trying to achieve, i am trying to pass this info from setTime(), into Time()

Comment: Maybe referencing `elapsedTime` in the code would let us see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok for clarity i will post the assignment parameters for better understanding in my Op, i posted another issue with this problem earlier got over that hurdle(i think) and am still stuck, i will post my full code as well.

Comment: i by no means expect anyone to sift through it all and do it for me, i just posted so the people who may help have a general idea

Comment: @Jason: It sounds like you want to call `setTime()` *from* the constructor - although your `setTime` probably shouldn't have any parameters if it's going to always use the current time...

Answer (score 2):

```
public Time() {
    setTime(0L);
}
```

Calling an overridable method inside a constructor is bad practice, though. You should thus make the method private or final, or make the class itself final.

Also, your method is a bit strange, because it takes a time as argument, but doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why would you want to call a class constructor from within a method of the same class?
The thing is that if you are accessing the class, you should have called a constructor before, unless your method is static, so for example, you could do this:

```
public static void setTime(long elapsedTime){
     ...
     new Time(elapsedTime);
     ...
}
```

Then from the invocation part:

```
Time.setTime(1L);
```

Although I think this could answer your question (if I understood correctly), the real question is why call a constructor of the same class from a method? Wouldn't it be better to just call the constructor and put all the logic of the method into it?
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help and i am sorry if i am being unclear in my own question, i think i am getting very confused as well.

Comment: Maybe what you need is just a `public Time(long elapsedTime)` constructor?

Comment: Says it needs to be a no arg constructor so that wouldn't work

Comment: But it also says that you have to add another constructor: "add another ctor that will take a single long parameter named elapseTime" or did I understand wrongly?

Comment: you are correct, but i already have that constructor setTime(long elapsedTime)

Comment: I get your point, but setTime is NOT a constructor. A constructor in Java has to have the same name as the class and has no return type, that is, it cannot return void, int, String, etc... You may want to look into Overloading a constructor. Check this page: http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors